# datatable with vue js and laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

Which is the best way to use datatable with vue.js and laravel ?
When I am using vuejs-datatable, I got the error

> Window.Vue is undefined

My project has  a router file. The same datable works fine in a separate project without router.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of datatable package avialable for vuejs.

Following links may help.

https://github.com/pstephan1187/vue-datatable

https://vuejsexamples.com/data-table-package-with-server-side-processing-and-vuejs-components/

Comment: I used bootstrap-vue data table and it works fine for me.https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/